# Haskell small CPU leak

Tags: haskell, cpu-usage, yesod

I’m experiencing small CPU leaks using GHC 7.8.3 and Yesod 1.4.9.

When I run my site with `time` and stop it (Ctrl+C) after 1 minute without doing anything (just run, no request at all), it consumes 1 second. It represents approximately 1.7% of CPU.

```
$ time mysite
^C

real    1m0.226s
user    0m1.024s
sys     0m0.060s
```

If I disable the idle garbage collector, it drops to 0.35 second (0.6% of CPU). Though it’s better, it still consumes CPU without doing anything.

```
$ time mysite +RTS -I0 # Disable idle GC
^C

real    1m0.519s
user    0m0.352s
sys     0m0.064s

$ time mysite +RTS -I0
^C

real    4m0.676s
user    0m0.888s
sys     0m0.468s

$ time mysite +RTS -I0
^C

real    7m28.282s
user    0m1.452s
sys     0m0.976s
```

Compared to a `cat` command waiting indefinitely for something on the standard input:

```
$ time cat
^C

real    1m1.349s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Is there anything else in Haskell that does consume CPU in the background ?

Is it a leak from Yesod ?

Or is it something that I have done in my program ? (I have only added handler functions, I don’t do parallel computation)

**Edit 2015-05-31 19:25**

Here’s the execution with the `-s` flag:

```
$ time mysite +RTS -I0 -s
^C      23,138,184 bytes allocated in the heap
       4,422,096 bytes copied during GC
       2,319,960 bytes maximum residency (4 sample(s))
         210,584 bytes maximum slop
               6 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0        30 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0001s    0.0003s
  Gen  1         4 colls,     0 par    0.03s    0.04s     0.0103s    0.0211s

  TASKS: 5 (1 bound, 4 peak workers (4 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.86s  (224.38s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.03s  (  0.05s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.90s  (224.43s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    26,778,662 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  96.9% of total user, 0.4% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0


real    3m44.447s
user    0m0.896s
sys     0m0.320s
```

And with profiling:

```
$ time mysite +RTS -I0
^C      23,024,424 bytes allocated in the heap
      19,367,640 bytes copied during GC
       2,319,960 bytes maximum residency (94 sample(s))
         211,312 bytes maximum slop
               6 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0        27 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0005s
  Gen  1        94 colls,     0 par    1.09s    1.04s     0.0111s    0.0218s

  TASKS: 5 (1 bound, 4 peak workers (4 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    1.00s  (201.66s elapsed)
  GC      time    1.07s  (  1.03s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.02s  (  0.02s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    2.09s  (202.68s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    23,115,591 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  47.7% of total user, 0.5% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0


real    3m22.697s
user    0m2.088s
sys     0m0.060s
```

mysite.prof:

```
    Sun May 31 19:16 2015 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       mysite +RTS -N -p -s -h -i0.1 -I0 -RTS

    total time  =        0.05 secs   (49 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc =  17,590,528 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE           MODULE                 %time %alloc

MAIN                  MAIN                    98.0   93.7
acquireSeedSystem.\.\ System.Random.MWC        2.0    0.0
toByteString          Data.Serialize.Builder   0.0    3.9


                                                                                           individual     inherited
COST CENTRE                 MODULE                                       no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                        MAIN                                        5684           0   98.0   93.7   100.0  100.0
 createSystemRandom         System.Random.MWC                          11396           0    0.0    0.0     2.0    0.3
  withSystemRandom          System.Random.MWC                          11397           0    0.0    0.1     2.0    0.3
   acquireSeedSystem        System.Random.MWC                          11399           0    0.0    0.0     2.0    0.2
    acquireSeedSystem.\     System.Random.MWC                          11401           1    0.0    0.2     2.0    0.2
     acquireSeedSystem.\.\  System.Random.MWC                          11403           1    2.0    0.0     2.0    0.0
 sndS                       Data.Serialize.Put                         11386          21    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 put                        Data.Serialize                             11384          21    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 unPut                      Data.Serialize.Put                         11383          21    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 toByteString               Data.Serialize.Builder                     11378          21    0.0    3.9     0.0    4.0
  flush.\                   Data.Serialize.Builder                     11393          21    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  withSize                  Data.Serialize.Builder                     11388           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   withSize.\               Data.Serialize.Builder                     11389          21    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    runBuilder              Data.Serialize.Builder                     11390          21    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  runBuilder                Data.Serialize.Builder                     11382          21    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 unstream/resize            Data.Text.Internal.Fusion                  11372         174    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
 CAF                        GHC.IO.Encoding                            11322           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        GHC.IO.FD                                  11319           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        GHC.IO.Handle.FD                           11318           0    0.0    0.2     0.0    0.2
 CAF                        GHC.Event.Thread                           11304           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        GHC.Conc.Signal                            11292           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv                      11288           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        GHC.TopHandler                             11284           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        GHC.Event.Control                          11271           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Main                                       11263           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                      Main                                       11368           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Application                                11262           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Foundation                                 11261           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Model                                      11260           0    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.3
  unstream/resize           Data.Text.Internal.Fusion                  11375          35    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
 CAF                        Settings                                   11259           0    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.2
  unstream/resize           Data.Text.Internal.Fusion                  11370          20    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
 CAF                        Database.Persist.Postgresql                 6229           0    0.0    0.3     0.0    0.9
  unstream/resize           Data.Text.Internal.Fusion                  11373          93    0.0    0.6     0.0    0.6
 CAF                        Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.Transaction      6224           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.TypeInfo.Static  6222           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.Internal         6219           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Yesod.Static                                6210           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Crypto.Hash.Conduit                         6193           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Yesod.Default.Config2                       6192           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  unstream/resize           Data.Text.Internal.Fusion                  11371           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Yesod.Core.Internal.Util                    6154           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Text.Libyaml                                6121           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Data.Yaml                                   6120           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Data.Yaml.Internal                          6119           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  unstream/resize           Data.Text.Internal.Fusion                  11369           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Database.Persist.Quasi                      6055           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  unstream/resize           Data.Text.Internal.Fusion                  11376           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Database.Persist.Sql.Internal               6046           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  unstream/resize           Data.Text.Internal.Fusion                  11377           6    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Data.Pool                                   6036           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Network.HTTP.Client.TLS                     6014           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        System.X509.Unix                            6010           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Crypto.Hash.MD5                             5927           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Data.Serialize                              5873           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  put                       Data.Serialize                             11385           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Data.Serialize.Put                          5872           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  withSize                  Data.Serialize.Builder                     11387           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Data.Serialize.Builder                      5870           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  flush                     Data.Serialize.Builder                     11392           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  toByteString              Data.Serialize.Builder                     11391           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  defaultSize               Data.Serialize.Builder                     11379           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   defaultSize.overhead     Data.Serialize.Builder                     11381           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   defaultSize.k            Data.Serialize.Builder                     11380           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Crypto.Random.Entropy.Unix                  5866           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Network.HTTP.Client.Manager                 5861           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  unstream/resize           Data.Text.Internal.Fusion                  11374           3    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        System.Random.MWC                           5842           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  coff                      System.Random.MWC                          11405           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  ioff                      System.Random.MWC                          11404           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  acquireSeedSystem         System.Random.MWC                          11398           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   acquireSeedSystem.random System.Random.MWC                          11402           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   acquireSeedSystem.nbytes System.Random.MWC                          11400           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  createSystemRandom        System.Random.MWC                          11394           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   withSystemRandom         System.Random.MWC                          11395           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Data.Streaming.Network.Internal             5833           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Data.Scientific                             5728           0    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
 CAF                        Data.Text.Array                             5722           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                        Data.Text.Internal                          5718           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

**Edit 2015-06-01 08:40**

You can browse source code at the following repository → https://github.com/Zigazou/Ouep

Comment: Any loading and initialization will count (`cat` doesn't show anything because it loads in <1ms). Does it increase further as time goes on? By how much?

Comment: Yes, it increases as time goes on. I discovered this behaviour when I was looking at `top`, seeing my site in the first ten processes. So I decided to test with `time` to have better numbers than `top`.

Comment: The `0.352s` timing could be the setup of the runtime + Yesod. For a better comparison, try waiting 1m and waiting 2m and subtract times: this should give you a better CPU/s estimation.

Comment: I added two more samples of the program running without idle GC. The leak increases as time goes on, meaning it is not the setup of the runtime and Yesod initialisation that have an effect

Comment: Actually the launching of my application takes approximately `0.080s`.

Comment: Nice. Maybe turning on the GHC profiling options will reveal something? https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html

Comment: Also, the RTS statistics (`+RTS -s`) would be interesting.

Comment: You should probably show us your code just in case, lest this be closed as off topic. Also, you might consider checking Yesod's bug tracker and perhaps filing a report.

Comment: @dfeuer I posted it here because I am new to Haskell+Yesod and did not know if this is a standard behaviour of Yesod, a known or unknown leak, something Haskell does in background, or something resulting of a commonly found pattern. That’s why I did not go straight to do a Yesod bug report.

Comment: @zigazou, the only time I can think of when wheel-spinning is not a bug in a system is when it's some kind of defense against side-channel attacks. That seems highly unlikely in this context. You should, however, include your code (however trivial you think it is), GHC version number, Yesod version number, and detailed reproduction instructions in your bug report. Also, there are already a couple tickets about excessive CPU use in certain circumstances. Check that none of them apply before you file a new one.

Comment: I'm using Yesod on an ARM project, and I'm seeing consistent 14% cpu usage there while its doing nothing.  Its not a total dealbreaker, but its close.  I'm going to try a test project in spock and see if that does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Found a [related bug](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/767) in the Yesod bug tracker.  Ran my program like this:

> myserver +RTS -I0 -RTS Development

And now idle CPU usage is down to almost nothing, compared to 14% or so before (ARM computer).  The I0 (that's I and zero) option turns off periodic garbage collection, which defaults to 0.3 secs I think.  Not sure about that implications for app responsiveness or memory usage, but for me at least this is definitely the culprit.